Getting and Error while opening the emulator in android studio-The emulator process for AVD Pixel_8a_API_31 has terminated
Getting and Error while opening the emulator in android studio-The emulator process for AVD Pixel_8a_API_31 has terminated.
Tried the step:

Enabled -virtualization in system -BIOS advanced tab(Restart system-Click deleted button to go to bios)

